# Why does my shell script register a successful exit when it fails?

Tags: python, bash, shell, exit-code

I have a shell script that executes [whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper/) on all files in a directory on a network device, and then stores the resulting transcript on the same volume. Sometimes something happens with the network (the volume is disconnected) that makes the saving of the resulting transcript to fail. This is a typical such error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 413, in cli
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.'
```

The relevant parts of my script looks like this:

```
    whisper "$file" --model large >> log
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "exit success: $?"
        echo "*****success****** $?, `uname -n`, $me"  >> "${directory}/../${transdir}/${name}.txt"
    else
        echo "exit error: $?"
        echo "*****error****** $?, `uname -n`, $me"  >> "${directory}/../${transdir}/${name}.txt"       
    fi
```

Normally, when the script finish successfully it enter the first if as expected, but even when I get an error message like the one above it still enters the first `if` as if it was successful. Why is that?

Note: AFAIK the writing to the `log` is not the problem.

---

Update:

```
% whisper --bad_args; echo $?
whisper: error: the following arguments are required: audio
2
```

---

Update 2:

```
#!/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from whisper.transcribe import cli
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(cli())
```

Comment: Some program(er)s don't know about return values? what does `whisper --bad_args; echo $?` output? Good luck.

Comment: `whisper` is crashing because of the error trying to create the directory for its output file. When a python script exits because of an uncaught exception. it has a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The `echo` statements won't show the exit status of `whisper`. The first echo shows the status of `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` and the second one shows the status of the first `echo`.

Comment: If you want to see whisper's exit status, assign `$?` to another variable before the `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar But why does it end up in the success clause of the if-statement?

Comment: What do you mean about programemrs don't know return values? Updated the question with the result of your example.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I know why it crashes.

Comment: it looks it goes beyond what is shown in Q as it should behave as you expect; just two things to clarify: could it be that you confused success/fail results since it'be good to echo to the same log exit success / fail results and see in one log file; second: do you have by a chance some wrapper script (not shown) whisper.sh that runs python ?

Comment: 1. I add the exit status to the end of the file that is produced so not to a log file. And I can clearly see that transcriptions that aren't complete still are marked as successes. 2. What do you mean? I have the script quoted above "transcribe.sh" that runs whisper.

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: It is possible that `whisper` is a wrapper which clumsily misplaces the exit code from the actual Python script it calls. `command -v whisper` reveals the full path; is the file it points to a shell script, a Python script, or something else?

Comment: @tripleee Added the full source code of `whisper` to the question.

Comment: Showing that whisper exits with a failure status when called with args other than those you are calling it with isn't useful. At `echo "exit success: $?"` you're no longer printing the exit status of `whisper`, you're printing the exit status of `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]`. Change `whisper "$file" --model large >> log; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]` to `whisper "$file" --model large >> log; ret=$?; echo "whisper exited with status $ret"; if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]` and then [edit] your question to show the output.

Comment: When the last command you run is `echo`, your exit status is that of `echo`.

Comment: Mind, _generally, you can only safely reference `$?` once_, because the moment you do anything with it you're setting a new `$?` value. So the very first thing you need to do is store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$?` is very volatile: the moment you `echo $?`, the value of `$?` is replaced with the exit status of `echo` and no longer refers to the exit status of `whisper`. Thus, you should store it in a variable before you use it if you might ever need it more than once.

```bash
if whisper "$file" --model large >> log; then
    echo "*****success****** $?, `uname -n`, $me"  >> "${directory}/../${transdir}/${name}.txt"
else
    whisper_rc=$?                    # <- THIS RIGHT HERE
    echo "exit error: $whisper_rc"
    echo "*****error****** $whisper_rc, `uname -n`, $me"  >> "${directory}/../${transdir}/${name}.txt"       
fi
```